# Rails detect if Attribute Changed Before Update - SystemStackError: stack level too deep

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, attributes, callback

I want to detect whether an attribute has changed before a model has updated.

I have the following (based on:http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html):

```
before_update :changed_attributes

def changed_attributes
    self.path_changed? ? puts('Path was changed') : puts('Path was not changed')
end
```

But now when i try t edit the Model.path attribute I get the following error:

```
SystemStackError: stack level too deep
```

Which I'm told means an infinite recursion is occurring.

What's the correct way to do this and without creating the SystemStackError?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that ActiveRecord already has a method called [`changed_attributes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html#method-i-changed_attributes). Most likely `path_changed?` calls `changed_attributes`, but you have redefined `changed_attributes` and it contains `path_changed?`. This results in an endless recursion and eventually a too deep stack level.

Try changing the name of your method to `check_changed_attributes` or something:

```
before_update :check_changed_attributes

def check_changed_attributes
  self.path_changed? ? puts 'Path was changed' : puts 'Path was not changed'
end
```